# Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2' on running npm install

Tags: docker, npm

I have a docker file I have built that uses the arm64v8/ arch type (I use an M1 Mac), no issues during the build at all, but as soon as try and install any npm dependencies I am met with this output:

```
root@456d8199a91d:/var/www/html# npm install  
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/www/html/node_modules/optipng-bin
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node lib/install.js
npm ERR! compiling from source
npm ERR! Command failed: /var/www/html/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/optipng --version
npm ERR! qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! optipng pre-build test failed
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c make install
npm ERR! pngrtran.c:99:1: warning: 'png_rtran_ok' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
npm ERR!    99 | png_rtran_ok(png_structrp png_ptr, int need_IHDR)
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
npm ERR! ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
npm ERR! ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
npm ERR! ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
npm ERR! pngxmem.c: In function 'pngx_malloc_rows_extended':
npm ERR! pngxmem.c:38:34: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
npm ERR!    38 |        (pngx_alloc_size_t)height > (pngx_alloc_size_t)(-1) / sizeof(png_bytep))
npm ERR!       |                                  ^
npm ERR! ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
npm ERR! /usr/bin/ld: ../libpng/libpng.a(pngrutil.o): in function `png_read_filter_row':
npm ERR! pngrutil.c:(.text+0x1f64): undefined reference to `png_init_filter_functions_neon'
npm ERR! collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
npm ERR! make[1]: *** [Makefile:100: optipng] Error 1
npm ERR! make: *** [Makefile:14: install] Error 2
```

I notice that it mentions `'/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'` which I only saw previously when trying to use the amd64 arch type for the same image build. My Dockerfile config is as follows:

```
FROM arm64v8/php:8.1-apache

RUN apt-get update

EXPOSE 80

RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    zip \
    curl \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    g++

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bz2 \
    intl \
    iconv \
    bcmath \
    opcache \
    calendar \
    mbstring \
    pdo_mysql \
    zip

ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/master/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions pdo_pgsql

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# This needs to be set in .env as 'UID', must match the host id, attained using 'id -u'
# prevents root ownership on apache + other saved files
ARG uid
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/devuser devuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/devuser/.composer && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser /home/devuser

# Necessary drivers for redis adapter
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
RUN pecl install -f redis

RUN sudo apt update
RUN yes | apt install vim
```

Im not sure why it errors with what looks to be the wrong arch type being used when I have specified `FROM arm64v8/php:8.1-apache`? Bare in mind I have used this config for a couple of months with no issues until today, is there something blindingly obvious I'm missing in the npm install output?

Comment: I have even checked with older branches that it's nothing to do with new npm dependencies being introduced that dont like the arm64v8 arch but still get the same output?

Comment: qemu-x86_64 is being used to run an x86_64 executable on your ARM machine, but to do that it needs x86_64 libraries.

Comment: If optipng is the particular library that's causing this problem by shipping an x86_64 executable, then... well, that library is what needs to be fixed. The `-bin` in `optipng-bin` implies that it's precompiled; if something is precompiled for the wrong architecture, well, there you are. I'd start by verifying that it's an optipng-bin module problem, and then look at that module's documentation / talk to its maintainers.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah that was it, removed from dependencies and installs fine, will look to get a solution for this, thanks mate!

Comment: (btw, in general, using node modules that bundle native binaries is a smell; it's not just prone to causing portability problems, but security problems too; easier to hide malware in machine-readable content than in human-readable code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @CharlesDuffy , as mentioned the version of optipng-bin I was attempting to install (2.0.0) was shipped with x86_64 libraries and nothing to support arm, bumping to 4.2.0 did the trick.